# Crossing document fields to determine the most recent

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on a software that read txt files that have several documents in, and determines which of these documents are the most recent... I need to cross the `docnumber` x `date` x `closing date`

For example:

file 'name1.txt' has the following documents in:

```
docnumber: m282378278292, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2010, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3983238923823, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 3030290909022, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2013, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: h287387322825, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
```

file 'name2.txt' has the following documents in:

```
docnumber: m282378278292, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 3983238923823, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 3030290909022, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2012, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3202930290239, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2015, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
```

file 'name3.txt' has the following documents in:

```
docnumber: 2298982918992, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 0434900990932, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 2290301112933, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
docnumber: 3944898uN2898, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43 (most new)
```

I need to cross these three fields to find out which are the newest. In the above example, the newests are:

```
docnumber: 3983238923823, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3030290909022, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2013, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: h287387322825, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
```

name2.txt:

```
docnumber: m282378278292, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3983238923823, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3030290909022, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2012, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3202930290239, date: 2009/09, closing date: 2015, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
```

name3.txt:

```
docnumber: 2298982918992, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 0434900990932, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 2290301112933, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
docnumber: 3944898uN2898, date: 2009/10, closing date: 2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43
```

I must compare the `closing date` only if `docnumber` and  `date` are equal. To illustrate, I just changed the year in the closing date, but it can have any kind of variation, not only in the year.

Anyway ... I was able to create dicts inside a list to represent each
file.

Interface of each representation:

```
{
    [file name]: {
        [date]: {
            [docnumber]: [closingdate]
        }
    }
}
```

Representation of the above files:

```
[
    'name1.txt': {
        '2009/09': {
            'm282378278292': '2010, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3983238923823': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3030290909022': '2013, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            'h287387322825': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43'
        }
    },
    'name2.txt': {
        '2009/09': {
            'm282378278292': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3983238923823': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3030290909022': '2012, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3202930290239': '2015, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43'
        }
    },
    'name3.txt': {
        '2009/10': {
            '2298982918992': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '0434900990932': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '2290301112933': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43',
            '3944898uN2898': '2011, 1, 5, 13, 59, 43'
        }    
    }
]
```

Desire output:

```
[
    'name1.txt': {
        '2009/09': {
            'm282378278292': false,
            '3983238923823': true,
            '3030290909022': true,
            'h287387322825': true
        }
    },
    'name2.txt': {
        '2009/09': {
            'm282378278292': true,
            '3983238923823': true,
            '3030290909022': false,
            '3202930290239': true
        }
    },
    'name3.txt': {
        '2009/10': {
            '2298982918992': true,
            '0434900990932': true,
            '2290301112933': true,
            '3944898uN2898': true,
        }    
    }
]
```

My question is ... how can I make this?
This is my first project in python, forgive me for asking a question without at least show what I tried ... but honestly I do not know where to start ...

I appreciate any help!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building first a *maxValues* dictionary and then compare it with original, main dictionary. The many `for` loops is due to your nested dictionary structure.

```
maxValues = {}
for d in dictList:
    for k1,v1 in d.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():            
            for k3, v3 in v2.items():                                
                maxValues[(k2,str(k3))] = maxValues[(k2,str(k3))] \
                                if (k2,str(k3)) in [i for i in maxValues.keys()] else ''

                maxValues[(k2,str(k3))] = max(maxValues[(k2,str(k3))], d[k1][k2][k3])

for d in dictList:
    for k1,v1 in d.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            inner = {k: v == maxValues[(k2,str(k))] for k, v in d[k1][k2].items()}

            d[k1][k2] = inner

print(dictList)
# [{'name1.txt': {'2009/09': {'3030290909022': True, 'm282378278292': False, 
#                             '3983238923823': True, 'h287387322825': True}}, 
#   'name2.txt': {'2009/09': {'3030290909022': False, 'm282378278292': True, 
#                             '3983238923823': True, '3202930290239': True}}, 
#   'name3.txt': {'2009/10': {'0434900990932': True, '3944898uN2898': True, 
#                             '2290301112933': True, '2298982918992': True}}}]
```

**Explanation**

First loop set walks through each nested dictionary element and builds a `maxValues{}` dictionary of one level with tuple keys and date values: `key = ('date': 'docNumber'); value = datevalue`. While building dictionary, loop set also replaces values using the `max()` function for any repeated pairing of `date/docNumber` where the larger *datevalue* item replaces or remains in dictionary at that key. Ultimately, `maxValues` holds the max datevalue element for each distinct `date/docNumber` pairing.

Second loop set walks through same above nested looping and re-creates the last nested dictionary with boolean values (instead of previous *datevalues*). To recreate this nested dicitonary, a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is used that compares the current loop value with the`maxValue` at current tuple key. Comparison uses an equality expression to yield either `True` or `False` .

Comment: Hm.. this is returning the error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: At what line? Are you sure posted dictionary is as actually as you posted?

Comment: I'm inserting the data inside tupples before... maybe thats it

Comment: Well... i made work, but the logic isnt correct @Parfait, check this result: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKoBJz?editors=1010 ... in this example, all should be true, because the second object is different.

Comment: Why should all be true? What second object? Aren't we comparing docnumbers? In posted example here you do so.

Comment: We only compare the closing date if the docnumber and the date are equal

Comment: See update using a tuple for maxValues' key for docnumber and date. All return true in result link example. Even changing all dates to 3/15, only last returned trues.

Comment: This isn't entire working yeat.  When I get home, I send u an example that is broken.

Comment: Hei @Parfait, checkout this example of inputs: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woBXqb?editors=0010 Do you know why the second one isn't working?

Comment: See update. Previously, the `if` logic compared strings to tuple keys but now compares tuples to tuple keys.

Comment: Yeap, is working now! If you don't mean, could you explain the logic behind? I'm very new to python, so it's very difficult to understand... i'm putting several prints because i want understand what is happening, but i just can't.... anyway... thanks!!!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Thanks for Bounty but you did not accept solution (tick mark to side). Also, see added explanation in answer.